# Backup Visual Studio Projects

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, windows-10

I want to format my computer and make a clean install of Windows 10 (Fall Creators Update), and I want make backup of my all visual studio projects (UWP apps).

In addition to copying project folders do I have to copy something else?

Answer (score 2):

you only need to copy the projects folder.

ideally you should be using a version control (like git) and not ask questions like this!